# Performance too slow when updating points of curve

Tags: python, bezier-curves

I have a python script which reads positions from a file and updates the points of a curve. However, the update is too slow. This is the code which updates the positions of the curve

```
    def _update_yarns(self):
        for yarnId, yarn in enumerate(self.yarns):
            polyline = self.obj.data.splines[yarnId]
            for point, node in zip(polyline.points, yarn):
                point.co = (self.positions[3*node+0], self.positions[3*node+1], self.positions[3*node+2], 1.0)
                point.radius = self.radii[node]
```

This takes 30s to be done. Is there something I could do to improve performance?

Comment: well, it depends on how large those data structures are...if you have millions of points or yarns then maybe 30s isn't too bad.  what does "yarn" contain?  one thing I might do is calculate `3*node` once instead of 3 times, but that might not change performance noticeably - but in general why do something 3x when you can do it 1x?

Comment: my data set contains around 5 million points, but those are read from a file in the HDD in less than 1 second, so seems weird that it takes so long to set the point coordinates in the blender object. I guess my main issue is that I have to create a new point to include that 1.0 in the fourth component. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: how are you reading them in from disk?  can you add the fourth component as you read it?

Comment: No. Is raw memory which is directly read it into a numpy array with np.frombuffer

Comment: I'd have to see more of the code to have any better ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use `foreach_set`, which sets a whole batch of things at once from an array. The array needs to go in the same order as the points.

For radii, you just need:

```py
polyline.points.foreach_set("radius", self.radii[yarn])
```

For the coordinates, try:

```py
# Reshape into an n x 3 array of vectors
coords = self.positions.reshape(len(coords)//3, 3)

# Add 1.0 in fourth component, making an n x 4 array
# NOTE: up to here can be done outside the loop
coords = numpy.hstack(( coords, numpy.ones((len(coords), 1)) ))

# Reindex to get a npoints x 4 array in order of points
coords = coords[yarn]

# Flatten into a linear 4*npoints array
coords = coords.reshape(4 * len(coords))

# You can now use foreach_set
polyline.points.foreach_set("co", coords)
```

(hstack might not be the fastest way, you could try others.)

Comment: Actually this doesn't work. The issue is that my points in self.positions are just a buffer of points and the node variable indicates where to access in that buffer. This comes from how I export my data, as an indexed based polyline. But blender doesn't use indices for splines, its just a sequence of points.

Comment: You should be able to index with yarn to get it to go in the same order as the points. I updated.

Comment: @scurest may find this of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486294/how-to-add-an-extra-column-to-a-numpy-array  Do like the `np.c_` for simplicity.